# Does an underscore before an existing function name have a special meaning in solidity?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

Within the uniswap v2 core contracts for a pair of coins, there is a mint() function. Within this mint function, there is an undeclared _mint() function. Does the underscore before the function name have some special meaning in solidity?

I have extracted the function below. I am having difficulty understanding what the _mint() function within the mint() function means and where it comes from if it is undeclared (as far as I can see)?

```
    // this low-level function should be called from a contract which performs important safety checks
    function mint(address to) external lock returns (uint liquidity) {
        (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
        uint balance0 = IERC20(token0).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint balance1 = IERC20(token1).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint amount0 = balance0.sub(_reserve0);
        uint amount1 = balance1.sub(_reserve1);

        bool feeOn = _mintFee(_reserve0, _reserve1);
        uint _totalSupply = totalSupply; // gas savings, must be defined here since totalSupply can update in _mintFee
        if (_totalSupply == 0) {
            liquidity = Math.sqrt(amount0.mul(amount1)).sub(MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY);
           _mint(address(0), MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY); // permanently lock the first MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY tokens
        } else {
            liquidity = Math.min(amount0.mul(_totalSupply) / _reserve0, amount1.mul(_totalSupply) / _reserve1);
        }
        require(liquidity > 0, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY_MINTED');
        _mint(to, liquidity);

        _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
        if (feeOn) kLast = uint(reserve0).mul(reserve1); // reserve0 and reserve1 are up-to-date
        emit Mint(msg.sender, amount0, amount1);
    }
```

Source: https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol#L121

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is usually a coding convention for indicating that the function is either `private` or `internal` (which basically means that you don't need to dwell on this function too much because there's nothing much that you can do with it anyway).

Comment: I guess the part I don't understand is how _mint() can work if it's not declared with a 'function _mint()'... anywhere. More for my learning than trying to use that internal function

Answer (score 7):

The `_mint` function comes from one of the contract's parents, the `UniswapV2ERC20` contract: https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2ERC20.sol#L40

The underscore prefix is a convention, as in some other languages, e.g. Python, that it is a "protected" function, i.e. can only be called from itself or a derived class.  Solidity can actually enforce this through the compiler and the `internal` keyword, so this isn't strictly needed, but improves readability.  Linters like `solhint` will complain if you don't begin an `internal` function with an underscore.

Comment: Thanks, this was the missing piece. It's from a parent contract, thanks!